# How to display the output of elasticsearch on any client through Restful api or http

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch and its plugin and ran few queries to get the idea how ES works. But now I want to fire a query from ES and get the JSON output on any client or any chrome plugin if any chrome plugin is there for it.
Read about the Sense plugin but i guess that's merged in Marvel now!

Comment: sense is integrated in Kibana, not marvel

Comment: ohkay my apologies, must have gotten it wrong. But could you tell me what should I do to get the JSON output of a query which is fired from ES on a client or chrome plugin

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood the question but does'n't the  [sense chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig/reviews?hl=en)  work ?

Comment: Yeah it works but I want to send http / restful api request from the ES and catch the response on a client